# raphaeljs moving a 'container' set

Tags: raphael

I'm trying to understand how sets work with transforms. Basically, I would like to have a 'container' set with all children in it, that I can move around the canvas.

I created a fiddle to show what I mean, this is a simplification of a larger drawing.  http://jsfiddle.net/thibs/Hsvpf/

I've created 3 squares, red, black, blue. Each are added to a set and then they are added to a main container (set). I've added outlines to show canvas and set.

Red and black sets do not have transforms on them, but blue does. Blue remains in the 'container' set... until the container gets a transform.

Why is that? I thought that transforms were applied to all the chidlren of the set...?

Thanks in advance

Here is the fiddle code:

```
var paper = Raphael('holder');
var container = paper.set();

paper.rect(0, 0, '100%', '100%').attr({
    stroke : 'red'
});

var rectRedSet = paper.set();
var rectRed = paper.rect(100, 10, 20, 20).attr({
    'fill' : 'red',
    'stroke-opacity' : 0
});
rectRedSet.push(rectRed);
container.push(rectRedSet);

var rectBlackSet = paper.set();
var rectBlack = paper.rect(150, 10, 20, 20).attr({
    'fill' : 'black',
    'stroke-opacity' : 0
});
rectBlackSet.push(rectBlack);
container.push(rectBlackSet);

var rectBlueSet = paper.set();
rectBlue = paper.rect(0, 0, 20, 20).attr({
    'fill' : 'blue',
    'stroke-opacity' : 0
});

rectBlueSet.push(rectBlue);
rectBlueSet.transform('t50,150');
container.push(rectBlueSet);

var containerBBox = container.getBBox();
paper.rect(containerBBox.x, containerBBox.y, containerBBox.width, containerBBox.height).attr({
    stroke : 'black'
});

//trying to get the entire container and its children to move to 0,0
//commenting out the transform below will keep rectBlue in the container...?
container.transform('t0,0');
```

Comment: OMG, what with all that unnecessary nested `SET`s. You made my cry. What exactly are you trying to achieve? **Tell me exactly what do you want to do with your rectangles?**

Comment: LOL don't cry, not worth it... 

I have a much larger drawing, the fiddle is a simplified version of it. 
Short: 
I'm trying to move all elements/sets as a 'group', so I can position the 'group' where it needs to go. BTW: container.translate(x,y) instead of transform does what I need, but it is deprecated.

Long winded:
The larger drawing is a series of dynamically generated elements. The elements need to be in sets because they are elements with text on/in them. I also use sets to add events. That said, one set is transformed. When this set is transformed it doesn't move with the container

Comment: I don't think transforms are propagated through to nested sets.

Comment: I agree with Neil. That is why I wanted to know what exactly you are trying to do, at least scale down the problem to something that we can look at and guide you if we can

Answer (score 0):

A "set" in Raphael is not like a "group" in SVG. A set in Raphael is just a collection of elements that you can manipulate at the same time. So when you set the transform on the container set, it is really just setting the transform on every element inside the set, overwriting any previous transform settings.

You can append or prepend to existing transformations in Raphael using "..." notation.You need to change your last line to:

```
container.transform("...t0,0")
```

But "t0,0" doesn't actually move anything anywhere. If you want to move the container so the top left corner is at 0,0, then you need to write:

```
container.transform('...t-' + containerBBox.x + ',-' + containerBBox.y);
```